# Excel: How to extract a word between two words

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to extract the word that is between the words "component/" and "/code" of column G. And display it in another column (H, in this case)

[image]

I'm using the following formula for cell G6142 but unfortunately it isn't working:

`=MID(cell,SEARCH("components/",G6142)+7,SEARCH("/code",G6142)-SEARCH("components/",G6142)-7)`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1,"components/"),"/code")`?

Answer (score 1):

Try

`=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1,"components/"),"/code")`